# How to apply a function when clicking on any <input>?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call the *`pocniKviz`* function when I click on any  *input* element.

```
function pocniKviz() {
    vreme1 = new Date();
    var vremeOd = vreme1.getHours() + ":" + vreme1.getMinutes() + ":" + vreme1.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("vremeOd").innerHTML = vremeOd;
    // kada se zapocne kviz iskljucuje se dugme za pocetak kviza i ukljucuje dugme za zavrsetak kviza
    document.getElementById("btnZapocniKviz").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("btnZavrsiKviz").disabled = false;
}
```

Like these

```
<input type="radio" value="Da" name="pitanje1">Da</input>
<input type="checkbox" value= "HTTP" name="pitanje2">HTTP</input>
<input id="pitanje3">
```

Comment: By the way, _input_ element is a self-closed element : it has no closing tag `<input type="text" … />`

Comment: Formatted first code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one listener to `document.body` and conditionally run the function if the target is `input`:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    pocniKviz();
  }
})
```